# Cannot change the text color of Attributed String

Tags: string, appcelerator

var attr = Titanium.UI.createAttributedString({
            text: value,

```
        attributes: [{
                type: Ti.UI.ATTRIBUTE_LINK,
                range: [0, value.length],
                value: Titanium.UI.ATTRIBUTE_UNDERLINE_STYLE_SINGLE,
            },
            {
                type: Ti.UI.ATTRIBUTE_FOREGROUND_COLOR,
                value: '#CD1625',
                range: [0, value.length],
            },
            {
                type: Ti.UI.ATTRIBUTE_UNDERLINE_COLOR,
                value: '#CD1625',
                range: [0, value.length],
            }
        ]


    });

    credDetailsValue = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        attributedString: attr,
        width: "70%"
    });
```

not working to change the color of the TEXT underline is working

Comment: https://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2016/04/how-to-change-the-color-of-links-in-attributed-strings/

Answer (score 0):

`ATTRIBUTE_UNDERLINE_COLOR` is only available on iOS (see documentation) and the `ATTRIBUTE_FOREGROUND_COLOR` works fine like this:

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor: 'white'
});
var value = "this is a text this is a text this is a text";

var attr = Titanium.UI.createAttributedString({
    text: value,

    attributes: [{
        type: Ti.UI.ATTRIBUTE_FOREGROUND_COLOR,
        value: '#CD1625',
        range: [0, 5],
    }, {
        type: Ti.UI.ATTRIBUTE_FOREGROUND_COLOR,
        value: '#00ff00',
        range: [5, 10],
    }, {
        type: Ti.UI.ATTRIBUTE_FOREGROUND_COLOR,
        value: '#0000ff',
        range: [10, 15],
    }]
});

var lbl = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    attributedString: attr,
    width: "70%"
});
win.add(lbl);
win.open();
```